# How do I cross referenced a variable with contents of a text file?

Tags: powershell

File has 2 fields, BinaryID and name.  I download files by the BinaryID and need to rename them.  The Write-Host example in the ForEach loop only echo's back the last line of the text file for each of the ID's in BinaryID's.

4468 TP_146_18.zip
4468 TP_146_18.zip
4468 TP_146_18.zip
4468 TP_146_18.zip
4468 TP_146_18.zip

```
$BinaryID = 3927,3988,4073,4151,4265

Get-Content -Path "D:\SIS\PS_Zips.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $BID = $_.Split(',')
}

ForEach ($ID in $BinaryID) {
if ( $ID -eq $BID[0] ) { Write-Host $BID[0] $BID[1] }
    Write-Host $BID[0] $BID[1]
}
```

Comment: Your loop is just repeating itself outputting the same values over and over. Why hav an array of BinaryId's in `$BID` if all you ever write to the console is elements 0 and 1 ? Also, it looks like your input file is actually in CSV format (without headers), so have you thought of using [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) for that?

Comment: Are the downloaded files literally called '3927' etc. without extension or anything?

Comment: the downloaded file would have a .zip ext.  Downloading isn't the issue, i get all the files i need, the the cvs file has a list of the binary ID's and names, i just can't seem to get the "If $ID = $BID rename to file1.zip and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for explaining that the downloaded files do have an extension (.zip)

One way of doing this is to use Import-Csv with the `-Header` parameter like this:

```
$downloadFolder = 'X:\Path\to\where\you\have\downloaded\the\files'
$BinaryID       = 3927,3988,4073,4151,4265

$data  = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\SIS\PS_Zips.txt' -Header BinaryId, FileName
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $downloadFolder -File -Filter '*.zip' |
         Where-Object { $BinaryID -contains $_.BaseName }

foreach ($file in $files) { 
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName { ($data | Where-Object { $_.BinaryId -eq $file.BaseName }).FileName }
}
```

The `Where-Object` filters the files to collect so only files with a BaseName that is in your `$BinaryID` variable are passed through.
Next, all you need is to find the corresponding data row by its BinaryId field and use the FileName field to rename the file.